# form issue migrating form play-2.0.4 to play-2.1.0

Tags: scala, migration, playframework-2.0

While trying to migrate one project from play version 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 I have got this error:

```
type mismatch found: play.api.data.Form[...]
              required: play.data.Form[...]
```

in all controllers with all types of Form[...]. In controller it looks like this:

```
import play.api._
import data.Form
import data.Forms._

val someform = Form(
       tuple(
       "name" -> text,
       "email" -> text
       )
  )
```

The view starts as follows:

```
@(form : Form[...])
```

All this provoke the errors mentioned above but only with the project that was created with version 2.0.4 and then migrated to 2.1.0.
And with project created from scratch with 2.1.0 all this works like a charme. Why is it so?
In addition if I specify fully qualified names in the view(of the migrated project) like:

```
@(form : play.api.data.Form[...])  it works fine....
```

Comment: Have you used the `javaCore` dependency in your `Build.scala`? If so, remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it... I have really added `javaCore` and missed that it will make the project - java project as it mentioned in the migration guide.

Comment: Could you add the solution as an answer?

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `javaCore` from your appDependencies in `Build.scala`. Otherwise Play will treat your project as a **Java** project which means your templates expect the Java API, in your case `play.data.Form` instead of the Scala API at `play.api.data.Form`.

Please note that this behavior is different from 2.0.x where you could mix Java and Scala without a problem.